# getResource in java web project

Tags: java, path, getresource

the structure of my project contains 3 main folders (like 3 projects included in 1) For example..

```
Main/java/..
Main1/java/..
Main2/java/..
```

in those 3 modules the source folder is java, my problem is how to use getResource method from Main1 to get file url from Main2. 
Using MyClass.getResource(/xxx/xxx/xxx) is pointing to Main1 root dir.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

As [javadoc for `getResource`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) says

> will first search the parent class
>   loader for the resource; if the parent
>   is null the path of the class loader
>   built-in to the virtual machine is
>   searched. That failing, this method
>   will invoke `findResource(String)` to
>   find the resource.

So, you should you have the class from Main2 in your classpath. An alternative is to implement your own `ClassLoader`, and implement the `findResource` method to load classes. Having the class in your classpath seems the more reasonable/easy approach (I personally think that messing with `CLassLoader`s is generally not a good idea, unless you *really* know what you're doing).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what i did is adding Main2/src/main/webapp to the class path and then i m giving just /web.xml as path from Main1 but it still throw  null..

Comment: @Brake: are you trying to load a class or a file (like web.xml)? In any case web.xml is under WEB-INF, so you should load WEB-INF/web.xml